# Match string with 2x space hyphen space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm fetching tracks from a database. Some results have to be removed. For example:

`Michael Jackson - Billie Jean // Good
Michael - Jackson - Billie Jean // Bad
Michael Jackson - Smooth Criminal // Good
Various artists - Michael Jackson - Billie Jean // Bad
// Some results have even more than two: space dash space`

I have set up a capturing group which should be matched if it occurs between 2 or unlimited times. However it is not working.

`/(\s\-\s){2,}/gi`

My example: https://regex101.com/r/Uorj2N/1

What I expected is that only the bad examples are matched. Can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: [`/\s-\s.*\s-\s/`](https://regex101.com/r/Uorj2N/2)?

Comment: You should probably just use `/\s-\s/g` and check the count of matches found. It should be "easier" for the regex engine than backtrack with `.*`.

Comment: You may not even need a regex for this. You could easily split each line then split again, then, as was mentioned already, check the counts. Something like `var a = s.split('\n'); a.forEach((v,i,a)=>a[i]=v.split('-').map(s=>s.trim()));` could be an alternative approach (`a` holds the result here).

Comment: An official answer entry is missing here. ;)

Comment: @JamesWilkins I marked a comment as an answer but that comment has been deleted.

Comment: You can't mark comments as an answer, you can only upvote them. ;)

Comment: Why are you using a regex?  Why not just split on `-`? Example: `var good = s.split('-').length > 2;` Probably faster.